# How to trigger the beforeinstallprompt event on my PWA?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I build a PWA using Angular 9 which can be seen [here](https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/musicng/) and I implemented an `beforeinstallprompt` event handler so as to offer the user a way to install the PWA as an app on the screen device. But it never receives this event. The Chrome PWA audit passes fine.

I wonder what I'm missing...

Here is how I handle the event:

```
public checkForBeforeInstallEvents(): void {
  if (this.platform.ANDROID) {
    if (!this.isInStandaloneModeAndroid()) {
      console.log('PWA - Listening on the install prompt event on Android');
      window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', this.handleBbeforeInstallAndroid);
      window.addEventListener('appinstalled', this.handleAlreadyInstalledAndroid);
      self.addEventListener('install', this.handleServiceWorkerInstallEvent);
      self.addEventListener('fetch', this.handleServiceWorkerFetchEvent);
    }
  }
}

private handleBbeforeInstallAndroid(event: Event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.installPromptEvent = event;
  console.log('PWA - Received and saved the install prompt event on Android');
}

private handleAlreadyInstalledAndroid(event: Event): void {
  this.alreadyInstalledEvent = event;
}

private handleServiceWorkerInstallEvent(event: any): void {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
      console.log('PWA - Caching custom resources for the service worker');
      return cache.addAll([
        './index.html', // Caching the resource specified in the start_url in the manifest file
        // is a prerequisite to receiving the beforeinstallprompt event from the browser
      ]);
    })
  );
}

// Listening to the fetch event is a prerequisite to receiving the beforeinstallprompt event from the browser
private handleServiceWorkerFetchEvent(event: any): void {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response) {
        console.log('PWA - Found response in cache:', response);
        return response;
      }
      console.log('PWA - No response found in cache. About to fetch from network...');
      return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
        console.log('PWA - Response from network is:', response);
        return response;
      }, function(error) {
        console.error('PWA - Fetching failed:', error);
        throw error;
      });
    })
  );
}
```

The last log statement I can see in the browser console is:

```
PWA - Listening on the install prompt event on Android
```

I hope to see this one some day:

```
PWA - Received and saved the install prompt event on Android'
```

Note that the following one never displays:

```
PWA - Caching custom resources for the service worker
```

The `manifest.json` file contains:

```
  "name": "Music Note Generation",
  "short_name": "MusicNG",
  "description": "A simple music note generator to see if it's possible to generate a melodious soundtrack.",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icons": [
    {
    ...
```

I can see in the `Event Listeners` tab in the `Elements` tab of the browser console, the `beforeinstallprompt` listener is registered.

UPDATE: I fixed the issue with solving this [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61634049/958373) first, then this [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61566237/958373) and finally changing the scope property in the `manifest.json` file from `"scope": "/"` to `"scope": "./"` and in the `index.html` file changing the `<base>` element from `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">` and the issue was then gone.